# Pandas Conditional value fill, dependant on precious row's value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, rows

```
Current Input:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
# initialize list of lists
data = [
        ['2017-08-17 04:00:00',      1        ],
        ['2017-08-17 04:01:00',      2        ],     
        ['2017-08-17 04:02:00',      None     ],    
        ['2017-08-17 04:03:00',      None     ],   
        ['2017-08-17 04:04:00',      None     ],
        ['2017-08-17 04:05:00',      3        ],     
        ['2017-08-17 04:06:00',      4        ],    
        ['2017-08-17 04:07:00',      10       ],
        ['2017-08-17 04:08:00',      11       ],     
        ['2017-08-17 04:09:00',      None     ],    
        ['2017-08-17 04:10:00',      11       ],   
        ['2017-08-17 04:10:00',      11       ],
        ['2017-08-17 04:11:00',      None     ],     
        ['2017-08-17 04:12:00',      12       ],   
        ['2017-08-17 04:13:00',      11       ]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'price'])
```

```
Desired Output:
    
data = [ date                        price    entry
        ['2017-08-17 04:00:00',      1              ],
        ['2017-08-17 04:01:00',      2              ],     
        ['2017-08-17 04:02:00',      None           ],    
        ['2017-08-17 04:03:00',      None           ],   
        ['2017-08-17 04:04:00',      None           ],
        ['2017-08-17 04:05:00',      3        3     ],     
        ['2017-08-17 04:06:00',      4              ],    
        ['2017-08-17 04:07:00',      10             ],
        ['2017-08-17 04:08:00',      11             ],     
        ['2017-08-17 04:09:00',      None           ],    
        ['2017-08-17 04:10:00',      11       11    ],   
        ['2017-08-17 04:10:00',      11             ],
        ['2017-08-17 04:11:00',      None           ],     
        ['2017-08-17 04:12:00',      12       12    ],   
        ['2017-08-17 04:13:00',      11             ]]
```

I am trying to make it so that a 3rd column named "entry" takes the value of column "price" if the price on the previous row is None and the current row's price is not none. I have tried the code below but it does not work. All it does is make the whole "entry" column None.

```
condition1 = (df['price'].shift(1) is None) & (df['price'] is not None)
df['entry'] = np.where(condition1, df['price'] , None)
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert values to numeric and non numeric to NaNs, because pandas processing `None` like `Nonetype` and `NaN` like `np.nan` same way.

I suggest dont use empty strings, because then get mixed strings and numbers and next processing with numbers should failed.

```
df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'], errors='coerce')
df['testNA'] = df['price'].isna()
print (df)
                   date  price  testNA
0   2017-08-17 04:00:00    1.0   False
1   2017-08-17 04:01:00    2.0   False
2   2017-08-17 04:02:00    NaN    True
3   2017-08-17 04:03:00    NaN    True
4   2017-08-17 04:04:00    NaN    True
5   2017-08-17 04:05:00    3.0   False
6   2017-08-17 04:06:00    4.0   False
7   2017-08-17 04:07:00   10.0   False
8   2017-08-17 04:08:00   11.0   False
9   2017-08-17 04:09:00    NaN    True
10  2017-08-17 04:10:00   11.0   False
11  2017-08-17 04:10:00   11.0   False
12  2017-08-17 04:11:00    NaN    True
13  2017-08-17 04:12:00   12.0   False
14  2017-08-17 04:13:00   11.0   False
```

Add `fill_value=0` to [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and compare by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and
[`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
condition1 = df['price'].shift(1, fill_value=0).isna() & df['price'].notna()
df['entry'] = np.where(condition1, df['price'] , None)
```

---

```
print (df)
                   date  price  testNA entry
0   2017-08-17 04:00:00    1.0   False  None
1   2017-08-17 04:01:00    2.0   False  None
2   2017-08-17 04:02:00    NaN    True  None
3   2017-08-17 04:03:00    NaN    True  None
4   2017-08-17 04:04:00    NaN    True  None
5   2017-08-17 04:05:00    3.0   False   3.0
6   2017-08-17 04:06:00    4.0   False  None
7   2017-08-17 04:07:00   10.0   False  None
8   2017-08-17 04:08:00   11.0   False  None
9   2017-08-17 04:09:00    NaN    True  None
10  2017-08-17 04:10:00   11.0   False  11.0
11  2017-08-17 04:10:00   11.0   False  None
12  2017-08-17 04:11:00    NaN    True  None
13  2017-08-17 04:12:00   12.0   False  12.0
14  2017-08-17 04:13:00   11.0   False  None
```

Comment: I have tried that just now but it does not work, I still get  a column of None

Comment: @blueorchid - are `None` misisng values? what is `df['test'] = df['price'].isna()` ?

Comment: None are just blanks, it appears as green text on jupyter notebook. Its type is NoneType.

Comment: @blueorchid - Can you try `df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'], errors='coerce')` add before my solution? Answer was EDITed.

Comment: i have tried that but it still doesn't work, just returns a column fill of None again :(

Comment: @blueorchid - If working with data from question it failed?

Comment: I get a whole column of False when I use the code

Comment: Its not a NaN it says None

Comment: @blueorchid - it working same, `None` and `NaN`

Comment: @blueorchid - So you use `df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'], errors='coerce')
df['testNA'] = df['price'].isna()` and then only `False` ? So no numeric values?

Comment: @blueorchid - is possible numeric has space like `"1 "` instead `1` ? then change `df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'], errors='coerce')` to `df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'].str.strip(), errors='coerce')`.

Comment: Yes thats right, i used those code but I get only false. The values in price has type numpy.int64

Comment: stripping did not work because AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: @blueorchid - what is difference between real price numeric data and data in question?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @blueorchid - in data from question all working well for me, for you not?

Answer (score 0):

Your column seems to contain strings, maybe this should work:

```
df['entry'] = df.loc[df['price'].ne('') & df['price'].shift(fill_value='').eq(''), 
                     'price'].reindex(df.index).fillna('')
print(df)

# Output
                   date price entry
0   2017-08-17 04:00:00     1      
1   2017-08-17 04:01:00     2      
2   2017-08-17 04:02:00            
3   2017-08-17 04:03:00            
4   2017-08-17 04:04:00            
5   2017-08-17 04:05:00     3     3
6   2017-08-17 04:06:00     4      
7   2017-08-17 04:07:00    10      
8   2017-08-17 04:08:00    11      
9   2017-08-17 04:09:00            
10  2017-08-17 04:10:00    11    11
11  2017-08-17 04:10:00    11      
12  2017-08-17 04:11:00            
13  2017-08-17 04:12:00    12    12
14  2017-08-17 04:13:00    11
```

Comment: When I try this, I get a 1 for the first row of the "entry column" and then no values just blank space for the other rows

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `print(df.head(10).to_dict('list'))`